# WPF app crashes when using Visual States

Tags: wpf

I have a strange behaviour... I have a button

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource FlatButton}">ASDF</Button>
```

And I have the template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="FlatButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
        <Rectangle Fill="White" Opacity="0." x:Name="Overlay" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0." x:Name="OverlayDark" />
        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />


        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="Overlay" TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState.Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                    <VisualState.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="Overlay" TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState.Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard TargetName="OverlayDark" TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard TargetName="OverlayDark" TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

so far so good. Now I start the application and as soon as I hover over the button the application halts. It also tells me that there are no source lines to show because all threads are currently working on framework code.

Now comes the thing. If I remove the normal state, everything is fine. For hovering at least. When I try to click the button the app crashes again. If I use DataTemplate Triggers, everything is fine.

If I use the [Microsoft reference template for buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates) the app doesn't even pop up, it immediately crashes. Using only the control template without the style or using it embedded inside the style doesn't make a difference

Using Visual States with a check box does not crash the app...

Any ideas on what exactly is happening here? To my knowledge this should be working without flaw.

Also I'm on .NET 4.7 and have some UWP, some .NET Standard and some .NET Framework projects in my solution, though it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Are you getting a NullReferenceException?

Comment: I'm getting nothing. No exception, no code lines, no stack trace. Just a page telling me that the program stopped and all threads were busy executing framework code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting a `NullReferenceException` when I moused over the button with your code. With the following change, it works correctly. You say you're not able to see what the exception is, so it's possible that I'm seeing a different problem, but it's worth a try.

```
<VisualState Name="MouseOver">
    <VisualState.Storyboard>
        <!-- 
        WARNING 
        This was throwing an exception when TargetProperty was an 
        attribute of Storyboard. The reason for that is not known. 
        -->
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation 
                To="0.5" 
                Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState.Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

`TargetName` can be on the `Storyboard` element or as an attached property on the `DoubleAnimation` element; it makes no difference for me. But I get the exception if `TargetProperty` is not used as an attached property on the `DoubleAnimation`.

The other visual states work for me just as you have them. I don't have any theory about why this might be the case.

Comment: Strange... nonetheless this fixed it. But the exact same storyboard worked inside a contenttemplate trigger... fishy...

Comment: Fishy indeed. I don't like it a bit. I'd leave a comment in there myself. (UPDATE In fact, now I have.)

Comment: I submited a bug report.. Let's wait and see what Microsoft says.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious.